# Azure ADB2C - Web APIs authentication for SPA and Daemon App

Tags: azure, api, authentication, single-page-application, daemon

I have an API project written in .NET which can be called from a Daemon App (desktop client) and also can be called from an Angular Website.  I have the Daemon App setup in Azure B2C with a client secret.  I have the SPA setup in Azure and also the API.

In the Startup.cs file of the API - I can secure the APIs for the Daemon App by doing the following:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = Configuration["AAD:ResourceId"];
                    opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AAD:Instance"]}{Configuration["AAD:TenantId"]}";
                });
```

The settings in appsettings.json are:

```
"AAD": {
    "ResourceId": "https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxxxx",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "xxxx"
  }
```

I can secure the SPA by doing the following in the API startup.cs:

```
 //Adds Microsoft Identity platform(AAD v2.0) support to protect this Api
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                    {
                        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    },
                    options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
```

The appsettings.json file contains the following:

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxx",
    "Domain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit" 
  }
```

I cannot figure out how to combine these two different authentication methods or even if this is possible.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been at this for nearly two days and just after posting this question, I found the solution.  So, I'll post here just in case anyone spends as long as me!!
In Azure for the API - add this into the manifest.

[image]

Then in API Permissions - add in this as a delegated permission.

[image]

For the startup.cs file - use this

```
 //Adds Microsoft Identity platform(AAD v2.0) support to protect this Api
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                    {
                        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    },
                    options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
```

And now my two apps can communicate securely with my API. A website I found useful was: https://yourazurecoach.com/2021/01/05/api-security-for-dummies-retrieve-more-user-information/